# ideal load time for a webpage with fields

Tags: load-testing, page-load-time

I am currently doing load testing of a webpage, which has many fields i.e form.io fields. I was successfully able to get the results using Jmeter. 
Now, can anyone help me with what should be the best/ideal time for a webpage to load? Many articles says it should be between 2-5 seconds, is that true? Do we have any article/blog telling this?

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to some surveys if page load time will be more than 3 seconds, 6-39 % of users will leave your page. You can read more details in [this](https://dzone.com/articles/detailed-guide-for-website-monitoring-2) article.